# where can I find FXTestConstructor (recording tool) for Jemmy

Tags: testing, jemmy, jemmyfx

Shura presents a test recorder called FXTestConstructor (Jemmy Constructor) for Jemmy in his talk at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-M5WKPKqr1s.

Where can I download this tool ?

Is it available to the public already ?

[image: Screenshot of the tool from Shura's talk.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry. I have not completed it.
I should just push it to open in the state it is.